# Installing YAF in Sitecore ... config password?

Tags: sitecore, yaf

I am trying to install /yaf/install on my localhost, 
I get to the screen enter config password: I enter "admin" as I am told that is the default
I keep getting "wrong password"

I have searched for the folder /forum/app.config
I do not seem to have one in my application.

please help if you can,
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you modify the `YAF.ConfigPassword` key in `app.config` as specified in step 5, section 2.1 of the [YAF Module Integration guide](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/services/~/media/Marketplace/Modules/S/Sitecore%20YAF/Documents/Copy%20of%20Yet_Another_Forum_Integration.ashx)?

```
<add key="YAF.ConfigPassword" value="_password_for_installation_" />
```

You need to change the value to something else and enter that having followed the other steps.

Comment: yes, i did that! it will not take that password I gave it. thank you though for your help. Regards,

Comment: here is some more information ... for those of you that may have this issue ... I found another <add key="YAF.ConfigPassword" value ... etc, in web.config not app.config. hmmmm, a bit different than when you run this as a Stand alone.